# How to implement an android app acting as FontProvider for other apps?

Tags: android, fonts, android-contentprovider, android-fonts

I am currently looking for a way to implement a "configuration" android app that acts as FontProvider ( Through contentProvider maybe ) to other apps I own.

The goal is to have the possibility to update this "configuration" app with new fonts that will be served to other apps.

So far, no example/guides/blog posts were able to describe the necessary steps to take

Thank you!

Comment: Indeed: extend ContentProvider.